# Can't bind to 'bsConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)

Tags: angular, datepicker, ag-grid

**Can't bind to 'bsConfig' since it isn't a known property of 'input'.ngtsc(-998002)
dashboard.component.ts(9, 20): Error occurs in the template of component DashboardComponent.**

I am getting below error where i have imported
 `BsDatepickerModule.forRoot(),`

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-1 col-md-3 col-ld-3 col-xl-3">
                  <label for="from_date" class="mt-2 required">FromDate</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm mt-2" id="from_date" formControlName="from_date"
                    placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" bsDatepicker [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"
                    [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : searchForm.get('from_date')?.invalid && searchForm.get('from_date')?.touched}">
                  <div class="invalid-feedback">Please select from date.</div>
                </div>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.